# How to indent a long ternary condition in Php?

Tags: php, coding-style, conditional-operator, psr-4, rulers

I have a long ternary condition in Php that exceeds the 120 hard rule.

What would be the right indentation according to PSR standard?

This is my ternary condition. The condition is a bit long, so the function call exceeds the 120 rule.

```
$variable = (condition) ? function() : $variable
```

Is this a valid indendation?

```
$variable = (condition)
    ? function()
    : $variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to put each part on new line so it is clearly visible what you do in the "if" part and "else" part:

```
$variable = (condition) 
    ? function() 
    : $variable;
```

Comment: And this adheres to PSR standard?

Comment: As far as I know PSR-2/PSR-12 does not specify how to write long ternary conditions.